# MongoDB: Get mactched document from findOneAndUpdate before update

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm performing a MongoDB query to update a document like below -

```
await this.activity.findOneAndUpdate(
     { _id: activityId },
     {
       $set: { isFlagged: //boolean_value },
     },
);
```

In the `update` part of this query, is there a way to get the matched document from the previous step?

Basically, to do something like this -

```
const data = await this.activity.findOne({_id: activityId})

await this.activity.findOneAndUpdate(
     { _id: activityId },
     {
       $set: { isFlagged: !data.isFlagged }, //toggle between the previous boolean value
     },
);
```

Is there a way to achieve this in a single query?

Answer (score 3):

Use `$not` in an update with aggregation pipeline.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "activityId": 1
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      isFlagged: {
        $not: "$isFlagged"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3qTwnJ7Dc9b)